# PHP simple_dom_html memory leak

Tags: php, parsing, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

So, I use the [simple_dom_html library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse HTML, however, there is a small memory leak because of this. The leak is small, however, I use this library so much, that in only 2 days, my server reaches 16 gigs of memory usage from this leak which is a huge issue.

To clarify, I am using `$doc->clear();` and `unset($doc);` after, however the memory does not clear.

before `str_get_html`: 649512

before `$doc->clear()`: 9773480

after `$doc->clear()` and `$doc = NULL`: 1127184

after calling `unset` on everything: 855664

(these are in bytes - what `memory_get_usage()` returns)

I'd like to note that I am using `str_get_html`. I have looked for hours for a solution on google, this site, and other similar sites, however nothing seems to fix the issue for me. If you need any more information, please comment below.

Why exactly is this memory leak occurring? Here is the script I'm running:

```
gc_enable();
echo "before str_get_html: ".memory_get_usage()."<br><br>";
$doc = str_get_html($response);

echo "before \$doc->clear(): ".memory_get_usage()."<br><br>";
$doc->clear();
$doc = NULL;

echo "after \$doc->clear() and nullifying: ".memory_get_usage()."<br><br>";
unset($response);

unset($doc);

echo "after unsetting everything: ".memory_get_usage()."<br><br>";
```

Here's a screenshot of my memory usage because of this: http://prntscr.com/ck4s78 - the part where the graph stops is 10 hours downtime because this crashed my server while I was sleeping. I started using simple_html_dom on the 17th, which is when the leak started. Between the 18th and 19th I stopped using it for a few hours, and the leak stopped, and the graph became a straight line again (normal ram usage).

Answer (score 1):

First of all unset($html); does not release memory, PHP does it by itself.
If you could show us your script that leaks memory maybe we could help more

Comment: I updated the question, and added the exact PHP file I am using. Ignore the cURL stuff, it is irrelevant to the issue, I already checked 3 times and cURL is not leaking memory. cURL is just so I can get the HTML to parse.

Comment: Actually, I simplified the code into as least lines as possible - the memory leak is still there to clarify.

Comment: I made huge html and tested it with your code, the results was:
before str_get_html: 1410056

before $doc->clear(): 17288560

after $doc->clear() and nullifying: 1878864

after unsetting everything: 1536456

clear works and there is a lot of information on internet about this library memory leaks. For parsing I use DOM core PHP library and never had memory leaks

Comment: There actually was a separate memory leak w/ DOMDocument which was fixed by clearing libxml errors. The only reason I am hesitant to use DOMDocument is because I do love the simplicity of simple_html_dom's CSS selectors. I suppose it would be a better idea to switch to DOMDocument - still curious why this leak happens, though.